# Ignore accents for interline spacing

Tags: line-spacing, diacritical-mark

I need to adjust how \LaTeX works with interline's spacing whitin a paragraph (and if possible between a title and a paragraph). The problem arises when I use the `Ponomar Unicode` font. It has áccent sign bigger and more vertical then usual. There is no problem with lowercase letters, but when I add an accent to a capital ones, it affects the interline space dramatically. See an example:

[image: Pater Noster]

or with small helpers

[image: Pater Noster2]

If I add `'` on top of `И` it adds about 1mm to the space. So there is the question: can I instruct LaTeX somehow to ignore diacrictics and accents when count interline spaces.

P.S. there is an example

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Ponomar Unicode}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\newcommand\буквица[2]{\lettrine[lines=2]{\setmainfont{Indiction Unicode}\color{BrickRed}{#1}}{#2}}

\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\буквица{О́}{тче} наш, И́же еси́ на небесе́х! Да
святи́тся и́мя Твое́, да прии́дет Ца́рствие Твое́, да бу́дет во́ля Твоя́, я́ко
на небеси́ и на земли́. Хлеб наш насу́щный даждь нам днесь; \'И оста́ви нам
до́лги на́ша, я́коже и мы оставля́ем должнико́м на́шим; и не введи́ нас во
искуше́ние, но изба́ви нас от лука́ваго.
\columnbreak
\буквица{О}{тче} наш, И́же еси́ на небесе́х! Да
святи́тся и́мя Твое́, да прии́дет Ца́рствие Твое́, да бу́дет во́ля Твоя́, я́ко
на небеси́ и на земли́. Хлеб наш насу́щный даждь нам днесь; И оста́ви нам
до́лги на́ша, я́коже и мы оставля́ем должнико́м на́шим; и не введи́ нас во
искуше́ние, но изба́ви нас от лука́ваго.
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can increase the spacing and make it neater.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: yes, increase spacing like
```
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
``` 
helps here. But the problem with the distance between a title and a paragraph still lefts here. Any solution for that?

Answer (score 4):

The Ponomar fonts has rather large ascenders and descenders, so enlarging the leading is necessary. Experimenting with your text shows that a factor 1.27 is sufficient to avoid uneven lines.

Avoid using `\setmainfont` in the body of the document; it's much better to define a suitable font face for the lettrines. I also typeset the lettrines ignoring the height of accented letters; add a suitable amount of vertical space before paragraphs starting with a lettrine.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{multicol}

\setmainfont{PonomarUnicode.otf}
\newfontface{\indiction}{IndictionUnicode.otf}

\newcommand\буквица[2]{%
  \lettrine[lines=2]{%
    \indiction\color{BrickRed}\IgnoreAccents{#1}}{#2}}
% avoid spurious warning about small caps
\renewcommand{\LettrineTextFont}{\normalfont}
% ignore accent height in lettrines
\newcommand{\IgnoreAccents}[1]{%
  \vphantom{A}\smash{#1}%
}

\linespread{1.27}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\буквица{О́}{тче} наш, И́же еси́ на небесе́х! Да
святи́тся и́мя Твое́, да прии́дет Ца́рствие Твое́, да бу́дет во́ля Твоя́, я́ко
на небеси́ и на земли́. Хлеб наш насу́щный даждь нам днесь; \'И оста́ви нам
до́лги на́ша, я́коже и мы оставля́ем должнико́м на́шим; и не введи́ нас во
искуше́ние, но изба́ви нас от лука́ваго.
\columnbreak
\буквица{О}{тче} наш, И́же еси́ на небесе́х! Да
святи́тся и́мя Твое́, да прии́дет Ца́рствие Твое́, да бу́дет во́ля Твоя́, я́ко
на небеси́ и на земли́. Хлеб наш насу́щный даждь нам днесь; И оста́ви нам
до́лги на́ша, я́коже и мы оставля́ем должнико́м на́шим; и не введи́ нас во
искуше́ние, но изба́ви нас от лука́ваго.
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

(The font are called by the font file name, because I don't want to add them in my system.)

[image]

You can be bold and keep the standard leading by telling LaTeX that no two lines are too near to each other. Some more leading, however, seems necessary nonetheless.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{multicol}

\setmainfont{PonomarUnicode.otf}
\newfontfamily{\indiction}{IndictionUnicode.otf}

\newcommand\буквица[2]{%
  \lettrine[lines=2]{%
    \indiction\color{BrickRed}\IgnoreAccents{#1}}{#2}}
% avoid spurious warning about small caps
\renewcommand{\LettrineTextFont}{\normalfont}
% ignore accent height in lettrines
\newcommand{\IgnoreAccents}[1]{%
  \vphantom{A}\smash{#1}%
}

\linespread{1.1}
\setlength{\lineskiplimit}{-\maxdimen}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\буквица{О́}{тче} наш, И́же еси́ на небесе́х! Да
святи́тся и́мя Твое́, да прии́дет Ца́рствие Твое́, да бу́дет во́ля Твоя́, я́ко
на небеси́ и на земли́. Хлеб наш насу́щный даждь нам днесь; \'И оста́ви нам
до́лги на́ша, я́коже и мы оставля́ем должнико́м на́шим; и не введи́ нас во
искуше́ние, но изба́ви нас от лука́ваго.
\columnbreak
\буквица{О}{тче} наш, И́же еси́ на небесе́х! Да
святи́тся и́мя Твое́, да прии́дет Ца́рствие Твое́, да бу́дет во́ля Твоя́, я́ко
на небеси́ и на земли́. Хлеб наш насу́щный даждь нам днесь; И оста́ви нам
до́лги на́ша, я́коже и мы оставля́ем должнико́м на́шим; и не введи́ нас во
искуше́ние, но изба́ви нас от лука́ваго.
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: that does exactly I want. Thansk a lot.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

If you don't want to open up the lines quite so much, an option is to allow `\lineskiplimit` to be negative which allows (in this case) up to 2pt overlap before the line spacing is increased. In practice (if you are reasonably lucky) the "overlap" does not actually overlap text just an accent on one line goes higher than a descender on the line above (but TeX will not warn you if they do clash).

This is egreg's example with linespread reduced to 1.1 and `\lineskiplimit` set to -2pt.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{multicol}

\setmainfont{PonomarUnicode.otf}
\newfontface{\indiction}{IndictionUnicode.otf}

\newcommand\буквица[2]{%
  \lettrine[lines=2]{%
    \indiction\color{BrickRed}\IgnoreAccents{#1}}{#2}}
% avoid spurious warning about small caps
\renewcommand{\LettrineTextFont}{\normalfont}
% ignore accent height in lettrines
\newcommand{\IgnoreAccents}[1]{%
  \vphantom{A}\smash{#1}%
}

\linespread{1.1}
\setlength\lineskiplimit{-2pt}
\setlength\lineskip{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\буквица{О́}{тче} наш, И́же еси́ на небесе́х! Да
святи́тся и́мя Твое́, да прии́дет Ца́рствие Твое́, да бу́дет во́ля Твоя́, я́ко
на небеси́ и на земли́. Хлеб наш насу́щный даждь нам днесь; \'И оста́ви нам
до́лги на́ша, я́коже и мы оставля́ем должнико́м на́шим; и не введи́ нас во
искуше́ние, но изба́ви нас от лука́ваго.
\columnbreak
\буквица{О}{тче} наш, И́же еси́ на небесе́х! Да
святи́тся и́мя Твое́, да прии́дет Ца́рствие Твое́, да бу́дет во́ля Твоя́, я́ко
на небеси́ и на земли́. Хлеб наш насу́щный даждь нам днесь; И оста́ви нам
до́лги на́ша, я́коже и мы оставля́ем должнико́м на́шим; и не введи́ нас во
искуше́ние, но изба́ви нас от лука́ваго.
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Essentially the same I was adding…

Comment: @egreg as always, you follow my advice